# Integrating Laravel Breeze API with NextAuth.js in Next.js v13.4 using AppRouter

Tags: laravel, next.js, laravel-breeze, app-router, next-auth

I'm seeking guidance on integrating my Laravel Breeze API with my Next.js frontend. While there are examples available for integrating Laravel Breeze API with Next.js using the Page Router for client-side rendering (CSR) and SWR for server-side rendering (SSR), the new Next.js v13.4 release introduced the App Router, which defaults to SSR for scripts. This offers numerous benefits, but I'm struggling to find instructions on using Laravel Breeze API with NextAuth.js in this context.

I've come across NextAuth.js as a potential solution, but I haven't found any comprehensive examples or tutorials demonstrating how to seamlessly integrate Laravel Breeze API with NextAuth.js in the Next.js v13.4 environment. Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Front-End : https://github.com/vipertecpro/nextjs-app-for-laravel-apis
Back-End : https://github.com/vipertecpro/laravel-react-dashboard

I'm constantly working on it to improve it

Comment: @Vipertecpro Great, this is what I was looking for, Basically you implemented the laravel/breeze-next package in next.js 13.4 with AppRouter. <3

Answer (score 2):

I also have the same issue working with next-auth and there is no sufficient material available for this
I built two types of auth systems in my solution I came up with:
This file is ***app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js***

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import {authenticate} from "@/app/(auth)/login/action";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"

export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            type: "credentials",
            credentials: {
                username: {label: "UserName", type: "text", placeholder: "Enter your username"},
                email: {label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "Enter your email"},
                password: {label: "Password", type: "password"},
            },
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                const {username, email, password} = credentials;

                const user = {
                    name: username ?? '',
                    email: email,
                    password: password,
                };

                const data = await authenticate(user)
                if (data.status === 200) {
                    return {
                        username: data.data.user.name,
                        email: data.data.user.email,
                        token: data.data.token,
                        role: data.data.user.role,
                    };
                }
                return null;
            },
        }),
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async session({session, token}) {
            let data = null;
            if (token && token.id !== undefined) {
                //Setting user if logged in by google
                const user = {
                    google_id: token.id,
                    name: token.name,
                    email: token.email,
                    image: token.image,
                }
                data = await authenticate(user);
            }
            if (token) {
                session.user = token;
                if (data !== null) {
                    session.user.role = data.data.user.role;
                    session.user.token = data.data.token;
                }
                session.user.isLoggedIn = true;
                return session;
            }
            return session;
        },
        async jwt({token, user}) {
            return {...token, ...user}
        },
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET_KEY,
    jwt: {
        secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET_KEY,
        encryption: true,
        maxAge: 5 * 60,
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: [
            '/login'
        ],
        error: '/register'
    },
    debug: true

};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export {handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

In this when the authorize function runs it sends the user object to  jwt and jwt sends it to the session to store it

In the case of Google I am checking if the token id exists in my case, the token id is Google ID i.e. if I logged in with Google then id variable is used as a password.

and data = await authenticate(user) is a custom function used to authenticate the user.

Resource: https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials

If u find any thing in this description incorrect or is there's any better way to do this please let me know.